# Why isn't there a good scheme/lisp on llvm?

Tags: lisp, scheme, llvm

There is Gambit Scheme, MIT Scheme, PLT Scheme, Chicken Scheme, Bigloo, Larceny, ...; then there are all the lisps.

Yet, there's not (to my knowledge) a single popular scheme/lisp on LLVM, even though LLVM provides lots of nice things like:

- easier to generate code than x86
- easy to make C FFI calls
  ...

So why is it that there isn't a good scheme/lisp on LLVM?

Comment: Is this question asking for real answers -- like, problems with LLVM and/or Scheme, either technical or social, that are keeping this implementation from being done? Or is it just complaining rhetorically, like, "Why hasn't anyone done the dishes?" or "Why is this bus so late?"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

LLVM provides a lot, but it's still only a small part of the runtime a functional language needs. And C FFI calls are uncomplicated because LLVM leaves memory management to be handled by someone else. Interacting the Garbage Collector is what makes FFI calls difficult in languages such as Scheme.

You might be interested in [HLVM](http://hlvm.forge.ocamlcore.org/), but it's still more than experimental at this point.

Comment: As far a I can tell, HLVM is dead.

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you saying that a garbage collector [in general] is why it's hard for LLVM, or just a [garbage collector for LISP] is too hard? Because I'm pretty sure there are languages in LLVM with Garbage collectors. The LLVM docs even **specifically mention Scheme.**

http://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html

Comment: @KatasticVoyage I mean that an efficient garbage collector is hard, because it's something that cannot simply be tacked on a code-generation framework such as LLVM. It's not impossible, and while it had not been done in 2010, it has been done several times over at this point. I'm not sure what to do with this answer now.

Answer (score 19):

For CL: [Clasp](https://github.com/drmeister/clasp) is a Common Lisp implementation on LLVM, and [mocl](https://wukix.com/mocl) implements a subset of Common Lisp on LLVM.

For Scheme: there's a [self-hosting Scheme->LLVM demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316234719/http://pygments.org/demo/55807/) and [a prototype LLVM backend for Bigloo Scheme](https://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/2077/34201/1/gupea_2077_34201_1.pdf).

For Clojure: there's [Rhine](https://github.com/artagnon/rhine-ml), which is a Clojure-inspired lisp.

Answer (score 13):

There's a very small and apparently unoptimised Scheme compiler here:

http://www.ida.liu.se/~tobnu/scheme2llvm/

Taking your question literally,

- Writing compilers is hard.
- A poor implementation like the one linked above can block new implementations. People going to the LLVM page see that there's a Scheme already, and don't bother writing one.
- There's a limited number of people who write and use Scheme (I'm one, not a hater, btw).
- There are lots of existing Scheme intepreters and compilers and there's not a screaming need to have a new one.
- There's not an immediate, clear benefit to writing a new interpreter using LLVM. Would it be faster, easier, more flexible, better in some way than the other dozens of Scheme implementations?
- The LLVM project went with another language (C) to demo their technology, and haven't seen a need to implement a lot of others.

I think that it could be a lot of fun for someone to build an LLVM-based Scheme compiler. The Scheme compilers in SICP and PAIP are both good examples.

Comment: Link's dead, but here's the [newest archive I could find](https://web.archive.org/web/20110226115214/http://www.ida.liu.se/~tobnu/scheme2llvm/) from February 2011.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the question or context, but I believe that you could use [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/), which is a Common Lisp that compiles down to C, and use the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler to target LLVM (instead of GCC).

I'm not sure what (if any) benefit this would give you, but it would give you a Lisp running on LLVM =].

Comment: Totally agreed. I think that's the major benefit of ECL over trival Lisp Compiler.

Answer (score 8):

One thing to keep in mind is that many of these implementations have C FFIs and native-code compilers that significantly predate LLVM.

Answer (score 5):

[CL-LLVM](https://github.com/sellout/CL-LLVM) provides Common Lisp bindings for LLVM. It takes the FFI approach, rather than attempting to output LLVM assembly or bitcode directly.

This library is available via Quicklisp.

Comment: Does it support modern iOS Xcode compilation? Is it actually usable in production? i.e.: does it support ARM64 and bitcompiling on iOS?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. I've not used this module. I have used [mocl](https://wukix.com/mocl) which works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

[mocl](https://wukix.com/mocl) is a compiler for a relatively static subset of Common Lisp. It compiles via LLVM/Clang.

Comment: Information on MOCL is scarce. 
What "static subset" of Common Lisp does it provide, precisely?

Answer (score 3):

> there's not (to my knowledge) a single
>   popular scheme/lisp on LLVM

Currently, `llvm-gcc` is the nearest thing to a popular implementation of *any* language on LLVM. In particular, there are *no* mature LLVM-based language implementations with garbage collection yet. I am sure LLVM will be used as the foundation for lots of exciting next-generation language implementations but that will take a *lot* of time and effort and it is early days for LLVM in this context.

My own [HLVM](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/hlvm/) project is one of the only LLVM-based implementations with garbage collection and its GC is multicore-capable but loosely bound: I used a shadow stack for an "uncooperative environment" rather than hacking the C++ code in LLVM to integrate real stack walking.

Comment: Update: there is one now, namely Mono.

Comment: There's also Clang nowadays, and Haskell has an LLVM implementation. Still no Lisps AFAIK. (Not saying Jon was wrong. Just providing an update.)

Comment: @SK-logic: AFAIK, last I looked (Nov 2010) Mono still didn't have a working garbage collector and I'm not sure what the state of Mono is since its developers were laid off. http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/mono-28-step-closer-to-reliable.html

Comment: This statement was inaccurate even in 2010 -- unless of course you somehow consider C, C++ and Objective-C to be a single unified language.   ARC also existed on LLVM in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Scheme2LLVM](https://github.com/melvinzhang/scheme2llvm), apparently based on SICP:

> The code is quite similar to the code in the book SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs), chapter five, with the difference that it implements the extra functionality that SICP assumes that the explicit control evaluator (virtual machine) already have. Much functionality of the compiler is implemented in a subset of scheme, llvm-defines, which are compiled to llvm functions.

I don't know if it's "good".

Answer (score 0):

GHC is experimenting with a scheme backend and getting really exciting preliminary results over their native code compiler. Granted, that's haskell. But they've recently pushed new changes into LLVM making tail calls easier IIRC. This could be good for some scheme implementation.

Comment: I think you mean the LLVM backend rather than a Scheme one.

Comment: How can you make tail calls easier? You just mark calls in tail position with "tail" and enable TCO...